# Access to a MDB file without the file system access in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have an input MDB file coming from a third party program. I have to read it in my asp .net application and then ask some related form to the final user.

At the moment, I can write the mdb file on the filesystem and read it, it works but sometimes this feature doesn't work and I have to restart the server.

The customer want to externalize the server and I can't write to the file system or even restart it so I'd like to read the mdb file in asp .net from a MemoryStream or maybe execute a conversion to a most readable format like XML, but I don't think it is possible.

So I'm looking for a solution to preprocess the access file.

I don't think it is possible to read it via javascript (only vbscript).

The only way I imagined is :

- [call a special application with a url code](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/71831-application-url-launch-local-application-from-browser/) like app://id the id is transmitted to a special application on the desktop, he will select his file and the content will be transmitted to the web app via web service
- after that the person should click on a button and he can process the different form associated with that data

that sounds me complicated for the final user

does someone have some feeling or idea about that case ?

**Edit**

The mdb file is uploaded via a http form contained into the web form.

Sometimes, after the upload, the application throw an exception and it can't use the c:\windows\temp. I have an error : Access not possible on the specified file.

I don't have a better information because the application is located in the internal network of the customer and I'm not there. So I have to ask them to reboot it.

Comment: Are you able to connect to it via a connection string using ADO .NET?

Comment: Yeah it works if I write it on the file system. but sometimes it hangs and the customer wants to externalize it

Comment: you need to figure out why it "hangs". Most likely the code you have is very poor.

Comment: by "externalize" I'm assuming the customer won't run the web app on the same server that the app generating the mdb is on? In that case, you'd have to have some sort of service to query from the web app to that server to return logical data, a CRUD, maybe MVC WebApi would help a lot here. As for your solution of restarting the server each time the mdb gets "locked up", that is most probably WHY the client wants to "externalize" it. It gets locked for a reason. Resolve the lock issue without restarting the server first.

Comment: the problem is described in the question. regards

Answer (score 1):

Quote: [Configuring Permissions for an Access Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/445z2s49%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When a Web application uses an Access database, the application must
>   have Read permission to the .mdb file so the application can access
>   the data. Additionally, the application must have Write permission to
>   the folder that contains the .mdb file. Write permission is required
>   because Access creates an additional file that has the extension .ldb
>   in which it maintains information about database locks for concurrent
>   users. The .ldb file is created at run time. [...]
>   Therefore, to use an Access database in an ASP.NET Web application,
>   you must configure the folder that contains the Access database to
>   have both Read and Write permissions for the local ASPNET user
>   account.

In other words, if you have no permissions to read and write you will not be able to work with .mdb.

There are following options available

1. If permissions cannot be done due to security reasons, but your web server has an access to the .mdb file location (both located in same network) then your client could setup a scheduled job which will backup/copy .mdb to another location where asp.net could have permissions to work with .mdb. This however will be a problem for syncing backup .mdb to production .mdb.
2. Setup a webservice to update .mdb. It will be hosted on the server where .mdb is located and will have all required permissions. Your application will work with .mdb through the webservice and does not require any permissions on .mdb.
3. Replace .mdb with SQL Server Express

Comment: The solution 1 and 3 are not possible. For the second solution, I gave the permission to the ASP .Net application. I will edit my question to better explain the problem with the HTTP upload.

Comment: Why does it say about c:\windows\temp, is it the directory where webform saved the file?

Comment: well I call : string cheminFichier = Path.GetTempFileName(); File.WriteAllBytes(cheminFichier, fileUpload.FileBytes);

Comment: This seems to be another problem which is not really related to the original question. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx the method will raise an IOException if temp directory is full of temporary files. Try to delete them and see if it helps. In general, I would suggest to use own directory for uploading files.